# Finding the function when given definite integral output

Tags: calculus, integration

Find a function $f$ and a positive number $a$ such that:

$$\int_{\sqrt x}^a f(x)\ln(x)\, dx= {\exp(x)\over2}-\ln\left({\sqrt x\over a}\right)-\pi$$

for all $x>0.$

Comment: Hint: Differentiate both sides with respect to $y$ and then solve for $f$. You can find $a$ by choosing $y=a^2$, so that the left hand side of the equation becomes $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\int_a^bf(t)\,dt=-\int_b^a f(t)\,dt,$ so we can do this:
\begin{align*}
\int_{\sqrt{y}}^a f(t)\ln(t)\,dt&=\frac{\exp(y)}{2}-\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{y}}{a}\right)-\pi \\
-\int_a^{\sqrt{y}} f(t)\ln(t)\,dt&=\frac{\exp((\sqrt{y})^2)}{2}-\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{y}}{a}\right)-\pi.
\end{align*}
Now let $u=\sqrt{y}$ to obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{du}\Bigg[-\int_a^{u} f(t)\ln(t)\,dt&=\frac{\exp(u^2)}{2}-\ln(u)+\ln(a)-\pi\Bigg] \\
-f(u)\ln(u)&=2u\,\frac{\exp(u^2)}{2}-\frac1u \\
f(u)&=\frac{1}{u\ln(u)}-\frac{u\exp(u^2)}{\ln(u)}.
\end{align*}
From here, we take Martins Bruveris's hint and set $y=a^2,$ so that the LHS of the original equation is zero. We obtain:
\begin{align*}
0&=\frac{\exp(a^2)}{2}-\ln\left(a\right)+\ln(a)-\pi \\
0&=\frac{\exp(a^2)}{2}-\pi \\
\frac{\exp(a^2)}{2}&=\pi\\
\exp(a^2)&=2\pi \\
a^2&=\ln(2\pi) \\
a&=\sqrt{\ln(2\pi)}.
\end{align*}